# Average glm summary of GLM loop

Tags: list, mean, glm, summary

Lets say I have several glm stored in a list and I want the mean of the results of those glm like the output of `summary.glm`.
Is there a simple way where I can get an output like the one from the `summary.glm` function (with the estimate, std error, z value, etc) where the result is the mean of all the models in the list?

Comment: What language is this? R? Can you include a reprex in your example? Much easier to copy-paste and then test solutions than remind myself glm syntax

Comment: Sorry, yes it is R language. I tried to edit my comment to include some reproducible example, but I cannot post it because of the following notification "Your post cannot be submitted at this time due to the volume of spam and abuse originating from your network. We apologize for any inconvenience. See the help center for more."